# Nextjs 9 Serverless proxy backend

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, next.js, serverless

With create-react-app you can create a setupProxy file and use http-proxy-middleware to proxy your backend calls like this:

```html
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

I tried finding the equivalent in a serverless nextjs application with no luck. I would appreciate any help.